# "Shield" als elektronische Platine

Tags: single-word-request

In einer Arbeit über Mikrocontroller (im Bild grün/schwarz) wurde der englische Begriff "Shield" mit "Schild" übersetzt. Diese Übersetzung halte ich für fragwürdig. Wie exemplarisch im Bild dargestellt handelt es sich um stapelbare Erweiterungen (im Bild rot), die über Steckverbindungen realisiert sind.

[image: Bauteil]

Sofern man den Begriff überhaupt übersetzen würde, welcher deutsche Begriff wäre der geeignetste?

Die vorgeschlagenen, mit *TECH* oder *ELEKT* gekennzeichneten [Begriffe von LEO](http://dict.leo.org/englisch-deutsch/shield) gefallen mir nicht sonderlich:

- Schild: wäre eher etwas wie ein Schutzschild, was nicht der Fall ist
- Abschirmung: wie im Bild zu sehen ist eher das Gegenteil der Fall
- Schirm: auch hier eher wie Schutzschirm, also nicht zutreffend
- Stulpe: darunter kann ich mir nur Socken vorstellen
- Abtrennung: zwar handelt es sich um eine abtrennbare Einheit, diese aber Abtennung zu nennen, würde der Funktion nicht gerecht

Die Erweiterung "Steckplatine" zu nennen könnte mit dem dazu gehörenden Begriff "breadboard" kollidieren und wäre auch missverständlich.

Comment: Vielleicht würde es helfen, uns genau das Bauteil zu zeigen, das im Englischen als *shield* bezeichnet ist...

Comment: Ich vermute jedenfalls, es sind die roten Platinen, die da pfannkuchenmäßig aufeinandergestapelt werden und das Dings um jeweils ein Funktiönchen erweitern... ?

Comment: @Takkat: ich habe die Farben im Text ergänzt. Es geht um die roten Platinen

Comment: Jetzt rate ich einfach mal wild, dass *shield* wiederum eine unglückliche Übersetzung aus dem Chinesischen ist. *Scheibe* vielleicht?

Comment: @Takkat Es ist eine "Erfindung" von Arduino.

Comment: Aha Arduino - dann haben wir's *cartellino* -> shield -> Steckkarte

Comment: Wenn das ganze eher so etwas wie ein Produktname einer Firma ist, spricht eigentlich nichts dagegen, den Begriff einfach unübersetzt zu lassen.

Comment: Ein *shield* ist insofern was Besonderes, dass man es nicht einfach irgendwo, sondern nur in einen *Arduino* stecken kann. Daher sehe ich wie @Annatar überhaupt keinen Grund, das irgendwie übersetzen zu müssen - *Arduino* versuchen wir ja auch nicht zu übersetzen. Im Gegenteil - jeder Versuch, das zu übersetzen, hört sich für mich tapsig an.

Comment: Auf einen Arduino gehört ein *shield*, auf einen Beaglebone Black ein *cape*, auf einen Papillo ein *wing* - Alles sind Steckplatinen, Modulplatinen, sonstwas, aber *shields* passen nur auf einen Arduino, *capes*, nur auf einen BBB, *wings* nur auf einen Papillo

Comment: @tofro: umso mehr sollte man den Begriff gar nicht erst übersetzen. Ich meine Du solltest das als Antwort schreiben.

Comment: @tofro Shields werden nicht nur in Zusammenhang mit Arduino verwendet. Auch für den Raspberry Pi werden verschiedene "Shields" angeboten.

Comment: @Gerhardh Die *shields*, die für den RPi angeboten werden, sind ganz normale Arduino shields, die mit einer Adapterplatine "passend gemacht" wurden. Für den Raspberry Pi scheint sich der Begriff *hat* (**h**ardware **a**ttached on **t**op) durchzusetzen.

Comment: @Takkat: Auch ohne das Bild zu vergrößern sieht man doch die Beschriftung "voice box shield"

Comment: Da eine solche Platine unterschiedlichste Dinge abschirmen kann halte ich die Behauptung, man könne sehen, dass hier nichts abgeschirmt wird, für möglicherweise zu eng gedacht (elektrische Kontakte?). Mit Raspi & Co. kenne ich mich aber zu wenig aus, um sagen zu können, was denn jetzt hier abgeschirmt wird.

Comment: @userunknown Der Begriff "shield" hat überhaupt nichts mit "abschirmen" oder "schützen" zu tun. Die shields tun nichts davon. Sie sind einfach große, flache Dinger, die vor dem Arduino sichtbar sind.

Comment: @tofro: Ja, sehr witzig. Große, flache Dinger, die vor dem Arduino sichtbar sind, wie Schilde/Schilder quasi. Keine weiteren Fragen.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In electronics SE habe ich [diesen Beitrag](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/158201/was-the-term-shield-in-use-for-daughterboards-before-arduino-became-popular) gefunden, wonach der Begriff von der Marketing-Abteilung von Arduino "erfunden" wurde, obwohl er eigentlich bereits eine ganz andere Bedeutung hat. Somit führen Übersetzungen von "shield" hier nicht weiter.

Mein Vorschlag wäre

> Steckplatine

auch wenn das bereits in der Frage ausgeschlossen wird. Allerdings halte ich Christians Vorschläge auch für sehr gut.

Comment: "Steckplatine" fand ich auch am naheliegendsten, aber ich verstehe auch Thomas' Einwand, dass man das dann mit der Steckplatine (Experimentierplatine, Basisplatine, Sockelplatine) verwechseln kann, die er als *breadboard* ansprach.

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann Eine *Steckplatine* ist viel zu generisch - Ein *Shield* kann man nur in einen Arduino einstecken - Eine *Steckplatine* irgendwo.

Comment: @tofro: Ich persönlich halte es für deutlich sinnvoller, Sprache in die Richtung zu formen (beispielsweise, wie im vorliegenden Fall, bei der Wahl von Neologismen), dass am Ende Arduino-Shields, HAL-Shields und isolineare Shields herauskommen (und ganz nebenbei der Oberbegriff *Shields* für alle 3), statt am Ende *Shields*, *Hurz* und *Furz* zu haben, die zwar konzeptuell alle dasselbe sind, aber Schnittstellen für unterschiedliche Zielsysteme aufweisen.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper ... nur leider fragt die Sprache nicht danach, was du oder ich für sinnvoll halten. Diese Begriffe entstehen "von ganz alleine". Teilweise haben andere Plattformen den "shield"-Begriff einfach übernommen, weil sie nicht kreativ genug waren, wieder andere haben sich ihren eigenen "hat" oder "wing" geschaffen. Die Leute, die das machen, haben ihren Fokus woanders als auf Sprache...

Comment: @tofro: "nur leider fragt die Sprache nicht danach, was du oder ich für sinnvoll halten" - in Fragen wie diesen werden Vorschläge für die beste Wortwahl gesucht und gegeben. Hat sich im allgemeinen Sprachgebrauch noch kein klar bevorzugter Begriff herausgebildet, läuft die Antwort exakt darauf hinaus, dass du, ich, oder ebenso andere Nutzer dieser Seite vorschlagen, was wir für sinnvoll halten. Im Übrigen hast du mit [deinem Kommentar](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/38908/38912#comment95919_38912) ja auch nichts anderes getan, als auszudrücken, was du (nicht) für sinnvoll hälst.

Answer (score 3):

Der Begriff *Shield* wird verwendet für Aufsteckplatinen, die einen **[Arduino](https://www.arduino.cc)** um z.B. Schnittstellen mit der Außenwelt erweitern. Im engeren Sinne beschreibt der Begriff eine Platine, die *nur* auf einen Arduino mit seiner speziellen Anordnung von Schnittstellensteckern passt. Der gewählte Begriff "Shield" scheint mit der Funktion eines Schildes (schützen, abschirmen) nichts zu tun zu haben, möglicherweise wurde er gewählt, weil ein *shield* etwas großes, flaches ist. Außerhalb der Arduino-Welt ist der Begriff *shield* für Erweiterungskarten oder Steckmodule nicht gängig. Im Gegensatz zum Begriff "Arduino" selbst scheint der Begriff *shield* nicht namensrechtlich geschützt zu sein.

Da der Arduino-Kleincomputer und damit auch die shields ihren Ursprung nicht im englischsprachigen Ausland, sondern in Italien haben, ist die Tatsache interessant, dass man dort nicht etwa einen italienischen Begriff (z.B. *scudo* oder *egida*), sondern einen englischen verwendet hat. Es scheint sich hier eher um einen *Namen* als einen *Begriff* zu handeln - Ein starkes Argument, das Wort nicht zu übersetzen.

Andere Kleincomputer mit einer ähnlichen Verbreitung wie Arduino verwenden ähnliche Kunstwörter als Bezeichnung für solche Platinen (die natürlich normalerweise nicht untereinander austauschbar sind):

- BeagleBone Black: *cape*
- Papillo: *wing*
- Raspberry Pi: *HAT* (dort ist das eine Abkürzung für "hardware attached on top")

Da solche Bezeichnungen spezifisch für bestimmte Rechnerfamilien sind, ergeben allgemeine Übersetzungen wie "Aufsteckplatine" oder "Modul" keinen rechten Sinn - Ein *Shield* paßt nur auf einen Arduino, ein *Wing* nur auf einen Papillo, ein *Steckmodul* irgendwohin - Es ist daher meiner Ansicht nach nicht sinnvoll, solche Bezeichnungen überhaupt zu übersetzen, sondern ich würde den englischen Begriff "Shield" auch im Deutschen verwenden - Das ist anscheinend auch allgemeiner Sprachgebrauch in der deutschen [Fachliteratur](https://www.amazon.de/s/ref=sr_nr_n_1?fst=as%3Aoff&rh=n%3A288100%2Ck%3Aarduino&keywords=arduino&ie=UTF8&qid=1504691880&rnid=1703609031) zum Arduino. Dort habe ich bisher nur das englische Wort gefunden.

Die am ehesten passende Eindeutschung wäre möglicherweise "(Auf)Steckmodul für Arduino", die aber erstens ein wenig sperrig ist, zweitens auch ein (eingedeutschtes) Fremdwort ist und drittens kein bißchen mehr Informationsgehalt als "Shield" transportiert. In einer Facharbeit würde ich den Begriff "Shield" einmal so erklären und dann die englische Bezeichnung verwenden.

Anmerkung: Die Welt des Arduinos kennt noch mehr solche Wortschöpfungen: Ein Programm, das auf einem Arduino läuft, wird dort nicht etwa "Programm" oder "Software" genannt, sondern *Sketch* - Arduino war ursprünglich gedacht, nicht-Computer-affine kreative Menschen an diese Technologie heranzuführen und hat wohl deswegen mit Bedacht Begriffe gewählt, die nicht aus der IT-Fachsprache übernommen wurden. Ob das unbedingt sinnvoll war, kann man sicher diskutieren, aber es scheint ein Kriterium gewesen zu sein, das man ziemlich konsequent durchgehalten hat.

Answer (score 2):

Wenn es das ist, was ich dem Bild nach meine, dann fände ich ein gutes Wort dafür eine

> Stapelplatine

oder auch

> Modulplatine

oder

> Aufsetzplatine

Jedoch habe ich solche Wörter noch nie gehört sondern mir gerade selbst anhand der vermuteten Eigenschaften des Gegenstands zurechtgefügt. Hier spricht also der von Fachkkunde unbelastete Laie.

Comment: Nennt man das wirklich *shield* im Englischen?

Comment: @Takkat Nur bei Arduino.

Comment: Stapelplatine klingt zwar wie ein gut geeigneter zusammengesetzter Begriff, scheint aber nicht weit verbreitet zu sein (Google Suche: 79 Treffer). Modulplatine könnte hinkommen (89000 Ergebnisse)